# when i push viewcontroller in navigation controller, shows black screen - empty view

Tags: ios, objective-c

i tried using storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and it was working fine but i needed delegate method so i added below code when opening 
SecondViewController from FirstViewController,

```
SecondViewController *svc=[[SeconViewController alloc] init];
svc.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

but it opens black screen.any sort help is really appreciated. Thank you.

secondViewController.h file

```
@protocol sendDataToAudioDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)sendData:(NSMutableArray *) data;
@end

@interface AudioSavedFilesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *fileTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *selectedIndices;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;
- (IBAction)selectedFiles:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,assign)id <sendDataToAudioDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
SecondViewController *svc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier @"identifier"]; 
svc.delegate=self;
```

You are trying to set SecondViewController's delegate property. But the error you are getting when doing so:

> property delegate not found on object type 'UIViewController'

Suggest that your SecondViewController class does not have a property called delegate. Hence you need:

```
@interface SecondViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

Comment: If that were the case, the code in his question would give a compile time error.

Comment: Which is why I think he is referencing the wrong scene from the storyboard. And explains why his code works with delegate. But with storyboard it doesn't because he is not referring to the correct scene that has the delegate...

Comment: @Tander yes, and the error `property delegate not found on object type 'UIViewController'` he gets when using storyboard suggests that he has forgotten to set the custom class of his view controller. So he is in fact instantiating a regular uiviewcontroller.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, hence my answer. I've asked him to check what class svc is once its been initiated from the storyboard. I'll bet its not SecondViewController ;-)

Comment: That actually just confirms my suspicion that you had the wrong class. Anyway, glad you found another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you're creating a completely new instance of `SecondViewController` and pushing it onto the `navigationController`. You're not using the `storyboard` scene at all, thus, all the `UI` elements you added and connected up won't work either. You'll need to revert to how you were doing it with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

You can still use the `delegate` as you're doing so there like this:

```
SecondViewController *svc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier @"identifier"]; 
svc.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

**Edit**
After reading your comments...
I think you haven't set the scene in your storyboard to use the `SecondViewController`.

So you need to replicate this: 
[image]

Comment: when i create controller using storyboard, it shows property delegate not found on object type 'UIViewController'

Comment: Are you using the correct identifier? Make sure you have set it in storyboard on the SecondViewController scene you want to push onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Did you set the class of the scene in storyboard to SecondViewController ?

Comment: i dont know exactly what you are talking about.. i am new to IOS.. can you explain in detail..

Comment: lets see your delegate declaration in the header file

Comment: _italic protocol sendDataToPrevious <NSObject> -(void) sendData:(NSMutableArray *) data; end **bold** are you talking about this one??

Comment: @grishma you also need to declare a delegate property e.g. `@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;`

Comment: @Tander i have set class, my logs in viewDidLoad of SecondViewController class is coming its just not visible..

Comment: @ØyvindHauge i have made my delegate object and used it in first class also  like `@property(nonatomic,assign)id<sendDataToPrevious> delegate;`

Comment: can you update your question with the complete header of your `SecondViewController`, please

Comment: @grishma Put a breakpoint after you instantiate the viewController from the storyboard. But before you set the delegate (Or comment that out) Then in the console type: po svc - what class does it show that svc is? I bet its not what you think it is.